# How to Save image in PC from a remote site Using PHP

Tags: php, image

Hey I am Using PHP Script to Generate Random Captcha Image from a Remote Website now i want to Save all the images in
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sav\

How to do this

```
<?php
$id= rand(11111,99999);
?>
<img src="http://jeemain.nic.in/jeemain2013/MyHandler/DisplayCaptchaImg.ashx?value=<?php echo $id; ?>" alt="Image">
```

I want to save the image in the Directory ../sav/
and name the images as $id.jpg
For Example 
$id= '22222'
so Image will be named as 22222.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming you mean you want to save the images on the same machine that is running PHP...

```
<?php
    $id = rand(11111,99999);
    $source = "http://jeemain.nic.in/jeemain2013/MyHandler/DisplayCaptchaImg.ashx?value=" + $id;
    $target = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/sav/{$id}.jpg";
    $Img = file_get_contents($source);
    file_put_contents($target, $Img);
?>
```

Note this will attempt to save the file on the *same machine* that is running PHP - that is, the server not your desktop (unless they're both the same machine).

Comment: tip: you can use `/` for paths in Windows. php will auto-convert to backslashes for you, saving you having to double-backslash everything.

Comment: hey Please help I had also tried by
editing file_put_contantes($target, $Img) 
to
file_put_contents($target, $Img);
but still didnt work for me

Comment: Nice catch on the semicolon but you need to give us a bit more information... How are you running the script? What error (if any) do you get? What's in the PHP server logs? Do you have `ERROR_REPORTING` turned on?

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee Are you sure the user PHP is running as has permissions to write to `inetpub`? That normally requires administrator permissions.